# Using @ sign in Tensorflow functions

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, python-decorators, python-class

I have seen that in Tensorflow tutorials, they usually put an "@" sign before writing the "tf.function[enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function)"

Why there is a need to do that? What happens if we do not put the "@" sign? In other words, where and when we should put an "@" sign when writing a function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is regarding just the @ sign or the @tf.fuction decorator.

It seems that you are asking about the @ sign. The @tf.function is just a Syntactic sugar.

You could do

```
@tf.function
def myFunc()
```

or

```
x = tf.function(myFunc())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is right. I think, I understood now.